# ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE" LINE 1: BEGIN DECLARE custo double precision default 0;

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I try declare one variable in a postgres but returning this error, but the sintaxe is correct according to documentation

```
DECLARE 
    custo double precision DEFAULT 0;

BEGIN
    custo = COALESCE((
        SELECT
            ROUND(CAST((SUM(e.saldo * e.vl_custo) / SUM(e.saldo)) AS NUMERIC), 3)
    FROM estoque AS e
    WHERE
        e.excluido = FALSE
        AND e.saldo > 0
        AND e.id_item = $1
        AND e.id_filial = 1), 0.0);

IF custo = 0 THEN
    custo = (
        SELECT
            ROUND(CAST(e2.custo_atual AS numeric), 3)
        FROM
            item_estoque AS e2
        WHERE
            e2.id_filial = 1);

END IF
```

i need create this variable in te select

Comment: You can't just run PL/pgSQL "like that". Procedural code needs to be enclosed in a [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) block. But such a block cannot return a result.

Comment: You need to read this [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).

Comment: Or, since you keep us guessing by not showing your full code, you define a function with `LANGUAGE sql` instead of `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to declare one variable in the select, this method is only on create a function in pgsql

Comment: This type of commentary is generally better provided as a comment on the question or answer you are responding to, rather than as an answer itself.